# How to get data from database as nested json using asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have data in sql server database like this :
[image: DB]

And I get this data as json using asp.net web api in this code like this :

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
        { 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from users", con); 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return Ok(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok("No Data Found ...");
            }
        }
```

And I get the data like this:

```
[
  {
   "user_id": 5,
   "frist_name": "John",
   "last_name": "{\"middle_name\":\"Ray\",\"lst_name\":\"Smith\"}",
   "user_name": "john@gmail.com",
  }
]
```

But I want view data `last_name` as nested json like this:

```
[
  {
   "user_id": 5,
   "frist_name": "John",
   "last_name": {
                 "middle_name": "Ray",
                 "lst_name": "Smith"
                },
   "user_name": "john@gmail.com",
  }
]
```

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable can not have any nested objects, so on the contrary you have to flatten

```
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)  return Ok("No Data Found ...");
     
    var jArr = JArray.FromObject(dt);

    foreach (JObject jObj in jArr)
    {
        var lastName = JObject.Parse((string)jObj["last_name"]);
        jObj.Property("frist_name")
            .AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("middle_name", lastName["middle_name"]));
        jObj["last_name"] = lastName["lst_name"];
    }

     return Ok(jArr);
```

output

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 5,
    "frist_name": "John",
    "middle_name": "Ray",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "user_name": "john@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

or if you don't need a data table then you can just parse last_name

```
    foreach (JObject jObj in jArr)
        jObj["last_name"] = JObject.Parse((string)jObj["last_name"]);
```

output

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 5,
    "frist_name": "John",
    "last_name": {
      "middle_name": "Ray",
      "lst_name": "Smith"
    },
    "user_name": "john@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: it's working for the second list only in my api, how can I aplly it for all list in api ?

Comment: @Kareem I updated my answer to fit for the all rows